# What is diffrence between Sun Mojarra and Apache MyFaces runtime environments?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using **JSF2** in web application but i am not able to understand what is this **Sun Mojarra** and **Apache MyFaces** runtime environments ? We can download **JSF** jars from the both the website . Can any one tell what are those two things ? As **JSF** Develop by **Oracle** [JSF Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html)

So what is this **Sun Mojarra** and Apache **MyFaces** in context of **JSF**?

Answer (score 0):

JSF is a specification. Mojarra and MyFaces are both implementations of JSF.

A specification theoretically defines how something should be.
An implementation is the practical real-world thing that is created according to the specification.

Comment: What about Primefaces,Richfaces these are also JSF implementation

Comment: No, that's wrong. They are just frameworks that can be used on top of the JSF implementations (Mojarra or MyFaces).

Comment: Richfaces, Primefaces are component libraries.